# Defining New Command with regular text inside math mode (Notation)

Tags: macros

I would like to denote the volume of a lattice as `vol $L$` and the determinant similarly as `det $L$`, so that the words "vol" and "det" are in the normal/regular text format but the L is in mathmode.  However, when I need to write it that way in an equation, it takes longer to type and I make more errors.

I want to write a new command so that I can type it all in mathmode similar to:  `$\vol L = ...$` and `$\det L= ...$`.

QUESTION 1:  Since `\det` is already a command, I cannot overwrite it.   What kind of font does it form when using `$\det\ M$` versus `det $M$`?

This is what I came up with for the Volume:

```
\documentclass[english]{article}
\newcommand{\vol}{\text{vol }}
\begin{document}
$\vol L = \sqrt{\left|\det(G\cdot G^{T})\right|}$
\end{document}
```

QUESTION 2:  Does it look okay if I use my new command `$\vol L$` and `\det\ L` together in the paper or should I use `$\vol L$` along with with `det $M$`?

Comment: You can use `\operatorname{vol}` or `\DeclareMathOperator{\vol}{vol}` with `amsmath` and always use it in math mode.

Comment: Also note that there is no `english` option for the article document class.

Comment: You surely don't want a regular space between “det” and “M” like in `$\det\ M$`; the spacing provided by `$\det M$` is the correct one. Don't worry for the closure: it happens. If you think that the answer provided to the linked question are not sufficient, please edit your question to say why.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).

Comment: Thank you!  All of your comments give me so much clarity.  I am deeply sorry that I didn't see the linked question.  I always try to spend a few hours searching for similar questions before I ask my own, but I just didn't see the linked question.  Your comments are very much appreciated!